# JUnit file structure, best practices (helper classes placement)

Tags: java, junit, gradle

**Established standards**

I organize my code, so that my `test`-folder has the same packages as my `main`-folder. My test classes, are named the same as my classes, but with *Test* appended.

*So far so good.*

**Problem**

I find myself creating a `util`-package in my `test`-folders, on my projects. And there I keep some project specific "test helper classes".

```
src  
│
└───main
    │   
    ├───java
    │   │
    │   ├─── myPackage
    │        MyClass.java
    │        AnotherClass.java
    │
    ├───test
        │
        ├─── myPackage
        │    MyClassTest.java
        │    AnotherClassTest.java
        │
        ├─── util
             NiceTestUtil.java
```

The "problem" is that I hate the asymmetry. A `util`-package in `test`, feels like it should be testing corresponding `util`-packages in `main`. Instead it contains my helper classes.

I've been thinking that maybe the `util` package belongs in `main`, but that doesn't feel right either, since it will clutter up main.

*I use JUnit 4.11, and Gradle (if it matters to anyone)*.

**Question:**

What is considered the best practice, file structure, for "test helper classes"?

Comment: That depends on where NiceUtil is used. Also, I prefer naming it "NiceTestUtil", so when someone else sees that class, he/she knows it's test code.

Comment: @Manu I changed the name to `NiceTestUtil.java`, like you suggested. It is used by more then one test class. So both `MyClassTest` and `AnotherClassTest` uses it.

Comment: If all tests using the same TestUtil are in the same package, I leave the tests and the TestUtil in the same package.
If, for example `test.a.b.c.OneTest` and `test.a.d.e.TwoTest` use the same TestUtil, I move it to the first common parent - `test.a.TestUtil` in this case.

Comment: Package name -> `testutil`.

Comment: Please mark any of answers as correct when you will feel there won't be any further answers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Placing the class into test part of project is correct.

The only thing that may help you: If the `NiceTestUtil` is used only for tests in `myPackage`, you can move that class to that package.

If it may be used by tests from other packages, I think you will have to live with this asymmetry :-)

There is nothing bad with it. It is a good practice to have symmetry in a way that production class -> test class. But it does not apply necessarily the other direction test class -> production class.

The last thing that comes on my mind is: If your `NiceTestUtil` can be used across projects, you can create a separate artifact (project) for it and use it as test-scoped dependency. This will remove asymmetry but for the cost of maintenance two projects (but removes possible `NiceTestUtil` code duplicity in future).

Answer (score 2):

My own rules for organizing classes in the test part are the same that for the main part: *Minimize always its visibility*:

- An API (method/class/etc) usable just for one class, should be private.
- If it is usable by several classes in the same package, should be public and be in a class with package access.
- If it is usable by several classes in other packages, should be in a public class in the most proper package.
- If it is usable by several projects, should be in its own library.

So far, so obvious. But with tester APIs, I follow two more rules:

- Keep a package structure parallel to the main part.
- Keep the testers *as simple as possible*, because the testers should be *reliable*, and if they are complex, they would deserve to be tested. In other words: **Favour simplicity over reusability**.